# Как кодировались данные на перфокарту?

Tags: кодировка

Такой вопрос - подскажите как кодировались данные на перфокарту? Какой-нибудь простой пример.

Гугл выдает много публикаций, но большинство из них пересказывает общую информацию из Википедии не углубляясь в детали. В других есть какие-то картинки, но они непонятные. Я из поколения next, так что не застал то время)) и вот теперь хочу разобраться.

Comment: https://www.masswerk.at/keypunch/
https://www.masswerk.at/cardreader/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Буквы кодируются по алфавиту двумя проколами, цифры по порядку одним проколом. Спецсимволы (кроме `&-/`) тремя проколами. На карте помещается 80 символов, номера проставлены сверху и снизу между строк.

Виртуальный кодер и ридер:

http://masswerk.at/keypunch

http://masswerk.at/cardreader

На схеме:

- слева номера рядов,
- верхний ряд без номера - кодируемый символ
- х -  прокол

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В двоичном режиме один прокол это 1 в бите. Машины использовали разный размер слова (бит в слове). На 36-битной машине на карту помещалось 2 команды процессора.

Comment: Что по вертикали, что по горизонтали? Где тут на картинке 1, где 2, а где три прокола? Какого черта они наискосок все? Ну и т.д.

Comment: @eri Спасибо огромное! То, что надо! А как понять, что буква кодируется двумя проколами? Я там на тренажере попробовал закодировать, так оно показывает только одну метку для каждой буквы.

Comment: Понял! Крестики вверху добавляются для букв в 12-й, 11-й и 0-й строках. А для символов есть еще крестики внизу в восьмой строке. А пробел, если.я правильно понял, никак не отмечался, т.е. эта линия в столбике была пустой, так?

Comment: пробел пустой, ещё возможен ввод произвольных данных

Comment: а что за три слэша? Один между R и S, еще один впереди в верхней не нумерованной строке, которая со всеми символами. И еще один в 12-й строке самый первый.

Comment: Тот что спереди - срез перфокарты

Comment: @maxMas тот что между r и s - знак деления.

Comment: @eri там два слэша впереди. Один в самой верхней, не нумерованной строке, там где указаны все символы. А второй чуть ниже в 12-й строке. Который из них срез перфокарты и что означает второй?

Comment: они оба срез угла на перфокарте http://chernykh.net/images/stories/fruit/perfokart.jpg

Comment: @eri огромное тебе спасибо еще раз! Почти все понял. Осталось только 2 уточняющих вопроса. Почему там сделаны пробелы в самой верхней не нумерованной строке, там где все символы, между 9 и А. и между Z и с? Кстати, что это за "с", оно какое-то не совсем "с"? И еще, ты говорил, что можно указывать произвольные символы, а как это делается?

Comment: @maxMas это просто пример с таблицей кодирования текста. Таблица может отличаться на разных машинах. И буква похожая на c это спецсимвол. Можно встретить такой же пример где на этом месте [

Comment: @eri ок, понял. Thank you so much!